# insert into / copy data from table to same with some changing value PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (select * from Mpl_Form_Responses t  WHERE t.form_ID = 1944 and t.response_id > 15) LOOP
    INSERT INTO Mpl_Form_Responses
      (Form_Id, Response_Id,remarks, Userid)
    VALUES
      (7399, i.RESPONSE_ID,i.remarks, i.userid);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

anyone know why its not working

Comment: How do you know it is not working? If you got error, show it. If results are not expected, explain what you are trying to do. Is Form_Id primary key? If it is, you won't be able to insert more than one row with the same id (7399). Anyway, what is the point of doing this in PL/SQL when you could have written a simple SQL query that would have done this faster?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: FORM_ID not a primary key  --- its as run time error  and if i put count(*) i have an three error ora -06550

Comment: Still you need to show us that run time error. ORA-06550 is meaningless without line number and exact error message that you got.

Comment: thanks GORAN i find the error it was the multi processes run in same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select rows and insert them to the same table with some changing like this:

```
INSERT INTO Mpl_Form_Responses(Form_Id, Response_Id,remarks + 'edited', Userid)
select  7399, t.Response_Id, t.remarks, t.Userid
from  Mpl_Form_Responses t  
WHERE t.form_ID = 1944
```

Comment: `+`  is not used for concatenation in SQL, use `||` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need PL/SQL for this:

```
  INSERT INTO mpl_form_responses
        (form_id
        ,response_id
        ,remarks
        ,userid)

   SELECT 7399 as form_id
         ,response_id
         ,remarks
         ,userid 
     FROM mpl_form_responses t
    WHERE t.form_id = 1944
      AND t.response_id > 15
```